# How get objects from a server thread that is running?

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, client-server

I have this structure in my program:

```
class Node0
  private Server server;
  ...
  public void init(){
      server.waitConnections();
  ...

class Server
  socket = ss.accept(); // ss :socketServer object
  handler = new Handler(socket);
  handler.start(); // start handler thread


class Handler
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        package = (Package) ois.readObject(); // ois :ObjectInputStream
        if (package != null) {
          this.setPackage(package);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
      }
  }
```

But now I need to get the package object in the Handler class in my Node0 class, how could I do that ? I receive the package in the `Handler` class, but now I should be able to send this object to my Node0 class, but if I try to get this value through:

```
class Node0
    server.getHandler().getPackage();
```

It launches a `NullPointerException`.

Any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: That's not even close to compilable. Please post some real code.

Comment: Don't catch exceptions, if you are not going to handle them. At least log them or rethrow them as errors. If `server.getHandler().getPackage()` is causing `NullPointerException`, `server` or `server.getHandler()` is `null`.

Comment: Ryan I don't paste the code because is three classes than my post would be very long, I was just trying to express my idea, okay ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but what you posted didn't express your idea very well because it's difficult to understand. You'll get the best results from posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try to use a callback function? You can't know when the Handler has set a package. You have to trigger the action from the handler.

Based on your very minimalistic example, not tested or even compiling:

```
class Node0
  private Server server;
  ...
  public void init(){
      server.setNode(this);
      server.waitConnections();
  ...
  public doPackage(Package p){
      // do something with p;
  ...

class Server
  public setNode(Node n) {
      this.node = n;
  }
  socket = ss.accept(); // ss :socketServer object
  handler = new Handler(socket, node);
  handler.start(); // start handler thread

class Handler
  ...
  public Handler(Socket socket, Node node){
    this.socket = socket;
    this.node = node;      
  }
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        package = (Package) ois.readObject(); // ois :ObjectInputStream
        if (package != null) {
          // this.setPackage(package);
          this.node.doPackage(package);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the package object in the Handler class in my Node0
>   class

Why? The code that processes the incoming data should be in the Handler class. Your Node0 class is or should be there just to execute the accept() loop. There's no reason for it to do anything else at all.